# Getting different UUID on same device with iOS version 10.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am using below code to get UUID.

```
 -(NSString *)updateUserPhoneDetails{
    
    NSString *retrieveuuid = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"com.testUser" account:@"testUser"];    
    NSString *uniqueID;
    if (retrieveuuid == nil) {
        NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
        uniqueID=[uuid stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"Create new uuid : %@",uniqueID);
        //Store the password in Keychain
        NSError *error = nil;
        [SSKeychain setPassword:uuid forService:@"com.testUser" account:@"testUser" error:&error];
    }else{
        uniqueID=[retrieveuuid stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"uniqueID  : %@",uniqueID);
    }
    return uniqueID;
}
```

The above code is working fine before iOS 10.0. I have tested in iPhone 7, iPhone 5s but getting some time different UUID. I think it should be same at every time when I re-install the same app.

Comment: [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]; will generate unique id every time when this called and it is not specific to iOS.

Comment: Why does it matter if you are saving it to keychain? You just save in the keychain one time and the next time you need to retrieve only. There is no need of updating keychain everytime.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Is it possible someone switched from using local keychain to cloud keychain?

Comment: @Poles, I am storing UUID string in my back end server and doing specific operation for that device. If I am getting different UUID string for same device then its making confusion for specific functionality.

Comment: @GautamSareriya : But you are fetching the UDID from your keychain right? Which is stored for the first time and one time when you used `[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]` to generate a new UDID. So you must check the stored keychain with the back end server. Not the newly generated UDID. Otherwise there is no use of Keychain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this,

```
 NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

Comment: Why? Saving identifier to keychain is more powerful. Also, this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dig into *why* your call to `passwordForService:` is returning `nil` (which it clearly is given your symptom). If `SSKeychain` doesn't provide an error, you will need to put logging or breakpoints inside the code to see the actual error code.

If it's not found, then you'll need to make sure you're successfully writing (you're not checking the error in `setPassword:...`). If it's successfully writing, but you can't read the next time you install, you need to check that you're not changing your access group or signing key. If it's not reading (or writing) because of permissions, you need to make sure you're not trying to read/write while the device is locked (unless you've set permissions correctly for this).

Basically, check your errors, and go from there.